# File download that worked under .NET 2.0 now only works under .NET4.6

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

The below code has worked fine for years using just .net 2.0. Now it stopped and will only work with .net 4.6 or higher. The remains unchanged. The debugger runs over the

> client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(sourceURL), destination);

line. But doesn't download anything anymore.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NewTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartDownload();
        }

        private void StartDownload()
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

                string destination = "Tools.exe";
                string sourceURL = "https://mysiteexample.com/download/Tools.exe";

                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(sourceURL), destination);
            }
        }

        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have the download started inside a using block and it’s async I’m pretty sure the WebClient is disposed before it even has time to send a request or at least handle it. You can’t dispose it if it’s doing downloading still

Comment: @Sami   Doesn't work when not wrapped in a using statement either.

Comment: Yes, don't mix async and sync code, you should be `await`ing all async methods.

Comment: You’ll need to store it somewhere outside the method. If you have it inside the method it will also be disposed after the method call finishes. Declare the variable in the class scope

Comment: @Sami  Tried that too, same results

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Henk, I was able to get some more info on my problem. My ISP starting requiring TLS 1.2. So I had to add the following code. Works fine now.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

So the resulting code is.

```
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

            string destination = "Tools.exe";
            string sourceURL = "https://mysiteexample.com/download/Tools.exe";

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;                
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(sourceURL), destination);
        }
```